# SVG in HTML: clip-path CSS issue in Android browser

Tags: html, css, svg, android-browser

I'm using SVG icons in my project.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="icon">
    <svg class="svgi_bar" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
        <rect width="512" height="512" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="icon">
    <svg class="svgi_world" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <rect width="512" height="512" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

**Then CSS**

```
.icon {float:left; width:64px; height:64px;}
svg {fill: red;}
.svgi_bar rect {clip-path:url('#svgi_bar');}
.svgi_world rect {clip-path:url('#svgi_world');}
```

And a long-long-long SVG defs in . It works шт all needed browsers: IE9+, Mozilla, Chrome, Safari.

The example: http://jsfiddle.net/seodata/7v7Nc/5/

The onliest issue is in Android browser: it shows only last icons from SVG definitions. All icons before are just red squares.

Could you please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Android and which browser are you using?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't have the clip paths inside the actual SVGs you want to display?

Comment: Android 4.2.2, and native Android borwser (Internet) 4.0

Comment: @JakeSidSmith Yes, it'll be dinamic classes on the page, I never don't know which icon I'll need to use.

Comment: How are they changed? Css / js?

Comment: Are you clipping something more complicated than a plain rectangle?  If not, why use clip paths at all?

Comment: @JakeSidSmith CSS classes added with Angular JS.

Comment: In that case, rather than changing the classes you could use ng-bind-html and replace the svg completely with the exact image you want to display?

Comment: Or just hide the unwanted icons with ng-show or "display:none".